# Which repository URL is displayed in the ROS wiki?

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, wiki, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our [tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg](https://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/) SVN repo we used to have a special branch for fuerte in the [/branches/fuerte](http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/!svn/bc/822/branches/fuerte/) directory. A couple of weeks ago, we moved the fuerte branch back to /trunk and the former /trunk branch to /branches/electric. The [tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.rosinstall](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/doc/fuerte/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.rosinstall) file in the rosdistro repository at GitHub and the repository information in the [release](https://code.ros.org/svn/release/trunk/distros/fuerte.rosinstall) repo at code.ros.org were updated accordingly.

For some reason the wiki pages on ros.org still show the old URL for fuerte for released stacks and packages, e.g. [hector_quadrotor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor?distro=fuerte). The last release was done from /branches/fuerte. The [Releases](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor/Releases) page displays the new, correct URL for the development branch in /trunk.

Which information source is used for the meta information of stacks and packages in the ROS wiki? Is there a difference for released and unreleased stacks? How can I force the indexer to update the information?

Edit: `roslocate uri` also shows the updated URL.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53658/which-repository-url-is-displayed-in-the-ros-wiki?/) by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1266 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-30**:
I would love to see wiki documentation for all the places where source URLs need to be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I found the answer by myself: For ROS electric and upwards, only the rosinstall files in the rosdistro repository at github ([https://github.com/ros/rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/doc)) are used by the [rosdoc_lite](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdoc_lite) indexer running on Willow Garage's build farm to decide which packages and stacks have to be documented and from which source URL and branch. rosdoc_lite also generates and uploads yaml files with meta information to [http://www.ros.org/doc/*distro*/api](http://www.ros.org/doc/groovy/api), which in turn are parsed by the wiki macros `PackageHeader`, `StackHeader` and `MsgSrvDoc` to create the package/stack meta information on http://www.ros.org/wiki/. http://www.ros.org/doc/api is a symlink to the API documentation for the current ROS distro.

All this is pretty well documented at the [wiki page of rosdoc_lite](http://ros.org/wiki/rosdoc_lite) and in the ["Get Involved" instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Get%20Involved#Create_Your_Own_.2A-ros-pkg_Repository) on how to submit new repositories.

The confusion regarding our stacks from the tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg came from the fact that there have been two different rosinstall files present with inconsistent source URLs in the rosdistro/doc/furte folder, one for the whole repository created by ourselves, and others for each of the released stacks that have been copied over from the old documentation system during the migration to rosdoc_lite.

Please add comments or edit this post directly if I missed some details.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2